# How to get column ordered by average of a field from some table in SQL

Tags: sql, average

I think that is not easy to understand what I need reading title, so I'll explain better.
My database is like:

Table1[image: Table1]Table2[image: Table2]Table3[image: Table3] and other tables like these...

Users will insert into textfield a value like `1` and I will show them only the name that contains `1`. I do this in this way:

```
ArrayList<String> found = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> allTable = getAllTableInDB();

for(String table:allTable){
    try {
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM '"+table+"'");
        while(rs.next()){
            if(!found.contains(rs.getString("name")) && rs.getString("name").equals(WhatUserInserts))
                found.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is to calculate the "best" of this name found ordering by average of column v.

For one table I know that I can use something like:

```
SELECT name FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY AVG(v) DESC
```

How can I do the same on this limit of value of some table?

I hope I explain my question well

SOLVED in this way THANKS TO `Dan P`:

```
ArrayList<String> tables = getAllTableInDB();
String query = "SELECT * FROM (";
String union = " UNION ";

for(int i=0;i<tables.size();i++){
    query+="SELECT * FROM '"+tables.get(i)+"' WHERE name LIKE '%"+find+"%'";
    query = i==tables.size()-1?query:query+union;
}

query+=") GROUP BY nome ORDER BY AVG(venduti) DESC";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the Max or Avg of all tables this will get you the max V value for name.  If you want Avgerage use AVG.  I didn't exactly understand the question but I think this what you want.

```
SELECT Name, Max(V)
FROM
(
  SELECT Name, v
  FROM TABLE1
  UNION
  SELECT Name, v
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION
  SELECT Name, v
  FROM TABLE3
) AS AllTables
GROUP BY Name
WHERE Name = 'Jon Doe'
```

After commenting you asked if you could enhance performance.  Yes by including the name in the where clause for each table assuming there is an index / primary key on the name.  You should probably used a table valued function if you go this route.

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Name = 'Jon Doe' 

SELECT Name, Max(V)
FROM
(
  SELECT Name, v
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE Name = @Name
  UNION
  SELECT Name, v
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE Name = @Name
  UNION
  SELECT Name, v
  FROM TABLE3
  WHERE Name = @Name
) AS AllTables
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: can i add WHERE condition to every select inside first FROM ?